# Display custom icon based on value of field in ArcGIS Online map viewer popup

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, icon

I have a point feature layer which contains ten fields which only contain a "Y" or "N" string. For Example:

| Location | Recycling | Indoor_Garden_ | Outdoor_Garden | Outdoor_Learning | Energy_&_Water_Conservation | Health_&_Wellnes | Maker_Space | Chickens | Greenhouse | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N | N | N | N |
| 2 | Y | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N | N | N |
| 3 | Y | N | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y | N | N | N |
| 4 | Y | N | N | Y | N | Y | N | N | N | N |
| 5 | Y | Y | Y | N | N | Y | N | Y | N | Y |
| 6 | N | N | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N | N |
| 7 | Y | N | Y | N | Y | N | N | N | Y | Y |
| 8 | Y | N | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N | N |
| 9 | N | N | Y | N | N | N | N | N | Y | N |
| 10 | Y | N | N | N | N | Y | N | N | N | N |

I would like to display an icon that represents each field (i.e. the recycling icon if the "recycling" field contains a "Y" at that location or a chicken icon if the "chickens" field contains a "Y" at that location) but no icon if there is a "no" in that field.  What methods could be used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer, use Arcade to create a new attribute field with data from the Arcade expression. You can use logic in Arcade to create a new column with data like Chicken-Y, Recycle-Y, or No.  Then set your symbol for each of the three value possibilities to your desired icon.

Many low or no cost materials for learning about Arcade. Example: https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/get-started-with-arcgis-arcade/